# How to join multiple tables without using navigation properties in C#

Tags: c#, repository, inner-join, service-layer

I have an **ASP.NET MVC3** application.

In my application I have the following **EF** classes (`hasCauses` and `isOfProblems` are navigation properties):

```
Problem {string ProblemId, string ProblemName, string ProblemDesc, bool solved, hasCauses}
Cause {string CauseId, string CauseName, string CauseDesc, isOfProblems}
ProblemCause {string ProblemId, string CauseId}
```

My **Repository** methods just return EF objects (same method for cause)

```
IQueryable<Problem> GetProblemsById(string problemId)
```

Now in my **Service** layer I have to create an object `SolvedProblems` that has to contain, among other fields, ProblemId and CauseId and of course they have to be related(according to `ProblemCause`). From my **Service** Layer I cannot "see" `ProblemCause` table because I do not use the navigation properties (they are used just in **Repository**). Therefore, I can create a method:

```
IQueryable<Cause> GetProblemsByCauseId(string causeId)
```

And fill the `ProblemCause` while iterating through the `Problems`. However, if instead of two tables (+ association) I have 3 or more tables interconnected? Is it worth to make this nested cycles or to bring all the logic to the **Repository** (where can I use navigation properties) and return `SolvedProblems` to the `Service`?

Answer (score 0):

If these are just simple joins, I think the easiest way to tackle this would be to create a view in your database and map `SolvedProblems` to it in EF.

Comment: Thanks! A good alternative might be to create a SolvedProblems class within the EF namespace, that basically contains the DB View? Of course this class is populated by a method in the repository that perofrm the joins at application level